# Got node-gyp rebuild status 1 issue when installed nodeBB

Tags: node.js, xcode, node-gyp

I was trying to install the nodeBB which is one of open source forum system.

When I try to run the command in [this github page](https://github.com/NodeBB/NodeBB). I got the error message below,

```
> mmmagic@0.3.15 install /Users/tyler/Work/forum/NodeBB/node_modules/mmmagic
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EPERM, utime '/Users/tyler/.node-gyp/0.12.7'
gyp ERR! stack     at Error (native)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 14.4.0
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/tyler/Work/forum/NodeBB/node_modules/mmmagic
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.7
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v2.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Darwin 14.4.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! mmmagic@0.3.15 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the mmmagic@0.3.15 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the mmmagic package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls mmmagic
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/tyler/Work/forum/NodeBB/npm-debug.log
```

Then I try to check this in mmmagic's github page. Seems nobody met the same issue. I was wondering maybe this is because my nodejs or machine environment?

My system is **OX Yosemite  Version 10.10.4**  And I already installed the xcode and xcode command line tool, also, gcc was there.

Anybody can give me a hand? Thx...

Content in npm-debug.log

---

```
8351 verbose rebuildBundles mmmagic@0.3.15
8352 verbose rebuildBundles [ 'nan' ]
8353 info install mmmagic@0.3.15
8354 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8355 info mmmagic@0.3.15 Failed to exec install script
8356 verbose unlock done using /Users/tyler/.npm/_locks/mmmagic-8554fb98045d0882.lock for /Users/tyler/Work/forum/NodeBB/node_modules/mmmagic
8357 verbose stack Error: mmmagic@0.3.15 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
8357 verbose stack Exit status 1
8357 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:213:16)
8357 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:110:17)
8357 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:24:14)
8357 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
8357 verbose stack     at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
8357 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)
8358 verbose pkgid mmmagic@0.3.15
8359 verbose cwd /Users/tyler/Work/forum/NodeBB
8360 error Darwin 14.4.0
8361 error argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
8362 error node v0.12.7
8363 error npm  v2.11.3
8364 error code ELIFECYCLE
8365 error mmmagic@0.3.15 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
8365 error Exit status 1
8366 error Failed at the mmmagic@0.3.15 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
8366 error This is most likely a problem with the mmmagic package,
8366 error not with npm itself.
8366 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
8366 error     node-gyp rebuild
8366 error You can get their info via:
8366 error     npm owner ls mmmagic
8366 error There is likely additional logging output above.
8367 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
8368 verbose unbuild node_modules/mmmagic
8369 info preuninstall mmmagic@0.3.15
8370 info uninstall mmmagic@0.3.15
8371 verbose unbuild rmStuff mmmagic@0.3.15 from /Users/tyler/Work/forum/NodeBB/node_modules
8372 info postuninstall mmmagic@0.3.15
8373 silly gentlyRm /Users/tyler/Work/forum/NodeBB/node_modules/mmmagic is being purged from base /Users/tyler/Work/forum/NodeBB
8374 verbose gentlyRm don't care about contents; nuking /Users/tyler/Work/forum/NodeBB/node_modules/mmmagic
8375 silly vacuum-fs purging /Users/tyler/Work/forum/NodeBB/node_modules/mmmagic
8376 silly vacuum-fs quitting because other entries in /Users/tyler/Work/forum/NodeBB/node_modules
```

Comment: Please add the content of `/Users/tyler/Work/forum/NodeBB/npm-debug.log` to your question (probably it is better to use something like http://pastebin.com/)

Comment: @Salem Just post part of it.

Comment: Seems we all have the same issue. Still waiting for someone to help us. :  )

Comment: People are too busy celebrating the fact that you asked the ten millionth question

Comment: @PyNEwbie  Really ?? Where can I find the counter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error states, you have some kind of permissions issue with `/Users/tyler/.node-gyp/0.12.7`. Check the ownership on the directory and that your user has read/write access to it.